# Riemann curvature of a unit sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

The Riemann curvature of a unit sphere is shown in many textbooks to be sine-squared theta where theta is the azimuthal angle of spherical co-ordinates.  But what is the significance of the angle and how would a value be assigned to it?

Comment: The curvature of a sphere is $\frac{1}{r^{2}}$

Comment: Are you confused about the Ricci curvature of the sphere having a term proportional to $\sin^{2}\theta$?  This is just due to the fact that $R_{ab} = \frac{1}{2}Rg_{ab}$

Comment: No, I mean the Riemann curvature tensor which has 4 indices.   The calculation for the unit sphere is standard and is given in many textbooks, presumably because it is the simplest possible case.

Comment: the Riemann tensor is trivial for the case of a 2-d space, the Weyl tensor is zero, the Ricci tensor has one nontrivial degree of freedom, which means that the Riemann tensor has one nontrivial degree of freedom.  The whole thing is just proportional to $\frac{1}{r^{2}}$, with terms of the metric to enforce the symmetry requirements of the Riemann tensor.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: I wonder if [this is what he means](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/gr/oz1.html).

Comment: Any point of the unit sphere is referenced by $2$ angles $\theta$ and $\phi$. The metrics of the unit sphere is $ds^2 = d\theta^2 + \sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2$

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): theta is the polar angle, not the azimuthal angle.